# get network call data(json) form chrome by javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get json data of xhrhttprequest that is stored in chrome by JavaScript.  I tried many solution but I can't seem to find a way.

For example if you go to [southwest link](https://www.southwest.com/air/booking/select.html?int=HOMEQBOMAIR&adultPassengersCount=1&departureDate=2019-04-30&departureTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&destinationAirportCode=DAL&fareType=USD&originationAirportCode=LAX&passengerType=ADULT&promoCode=&reset=true&returnDate=&returnTimeOfDay=ALL_DAY&seniorPassengersCount=0&tripType=oneway) and do inspect page to see xhr calls by name shopping, if you preview it, it will show `json`.

Can someone please help me to find how can I get that data in JavaScript variable. Fyi I tried `xmlRequest()` function it gives me `400`. and also tried through `postman` which gives `403` there.

Comment: It is little unclear, what you are trying to achieve . based on the error code,, 400 is bad request may be the url is wrong and 403 is forbidden some authentication problem you need to pass some authentication parameter

Comment: i mean if we use headless browser to make api call it throws 403 error, but same response you can clearly see if you open above mention link. or just go to site. no worries i found my ans.

Answer (score 0):

i found that all the json data is stored in SessionStorage on chrome so i can get it by just `return window.SessionStorage.getEntries()` executing this command